# Gram-Schmidt Process, finding orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, orthonormal

Suppose I'm given $2$ random vectors $(v_1,v_2)$

I want to find orthonormal basis $(w_1,w_2)$

**Are the following equivalent?** for the $w_2$ case

$$w_1=\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|}$$
$$x_2=v_2-\frac{(v_1,v_2)}{(v_1,v_1)}v_1$$

**or**
$$x_2=v_2-(v_1,v_2)v_1 $$ **or** $$x_2=v_2-\frac{(w_1,v_2)}{(w_1,w_1)}w_1$$

**or** $$x_2=v_2-(w_1,v_2)w_1 $$

and then $$w_2=\frac{x_2}{\|x_2\|}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know that $\|v\|^2 = (v,v)$? No, not all of them are equivalent.

Comment: yes, well I usuall use the first case (for $x_2$), but they all seem to be projections

Comment: Is $x \mapsto v - (v,x)v$ indeed a projection if $\|v\|\neq 1$? What's $\|v -(v,v)v\|$ in this case?

Comment: It's a projection of $x$ along $v$, but since $v$ and $w$ are the same vectors, I thought it would be the same. $\| v(v,v)\|=(v,v)^{3/2}$, but $\|v-v(v,v)\|=0$

Comment: I don't see how this implies it's not a projection. We simply projected $v$ along itself. Could you tell me the correct ones I could use for Gram Schmidt

Comment: Consider $v=(1,1)^T.$ Then, $\|v\|^2 = (v,v) = 2$ and $v - (v,v)v = v - 2v = -v \neq 0$. Also, I meant projection in the sense that it's selfadjoint and idempotent. If $\|v\|\neq 1$, then these operators are not idempotent.